# "\b" acting improperly in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, escaping

I have a small bit of code that seems to be acting improperly; I'm new to Python, and imagine I'm overlooking something. The code is:

```
bs = ("\b", "\b", "\b", "\b", "\b", "\b", "\b", "\b", "\b");
print "b%ra%rc%rk%rs%rl%ra%rs%rh%r" % bs;
print "b%sa%sc%sk%ss%sl%sa%ss%sh%s" % bs;
```

When I run this in Powershell the output is:

```
b\x08a\x08c\x08k\x08s\x08l\x08a\x08s\x08h\x08
h
```

Why does the last `h\b` evaluate to `h` when using string (`%s`) output, when it seems like it should be deleted from the raw (`%r`) output?

Comment: BTW, `;` semicolons are *not* needed in python code. Please don't use them, you are making my sensibilities smart...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is this considered a taboo in Python? Can it cause any issues down the line? I'm teaching myself, and coming from C#... Semicolons are, more or less, habitual.

Comment: They won't cause issues; they can be used to separate simple statements onto one line.

Comment: Noted; I'll get out of the habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not *erasing* the character with a `\b`; you are only backing up one position.

So the characters are overwritten by the next printed character instead. Add a space and it works:

```
>>> print "b%sa%sc%sk%ss%sl%sa%ss%sh%s " % bs
```

Comment: Ah, my mistake! Figured it'd be something simple like that... Thanks for the clarification.